# What does if (@array) mean in perl?

Tags: perl, scripting

What does this mean in Perl?

1. `if (@array)`
2. `if (!@array)`

Does this mean if we ask Perl to check if array exists or not?

Thanks

Comment: it is not possible for there to be an array that does not exist

Comment: @ysth: A corollary of that is *"every array already exists"*, which is nonsense. It is very straightforward to write a program that refers to an undeclared variable. If `use strict 'vars'` is in effect then perl will prevent you from running the program, or if not then the variable will br created for the purpose of the reference. In neither case did the array exist before it was referred to.

Comment: no, the corollary is "every array mentioned, exists", which is true.  ('declared' is a separate issue)

Comment: @ysth: Your statement doesn't talk about *mentioned* arrays, just arrays in general

Comment: if it's not mentioned, it isn't worth mentioning :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An array in scalar context returns the number of elements. So the `if(@array)` checks if the array has any elements or not. It's similar to `if(scalar(@array)!=0)`.

Answer (score 11):

In Perl, an array in scalar context evaluates to the number of elements in the array. So

```
my @array = ('a', 'b');
my $n = @array;
```

sets `$n` to 2.

Also, `if` applies a scalar context to its parameter. So

```
my @array = ('a', 'b');
if (@array) { ...
```

is the same as

```
if (2) { ...
```

and, because 2 is considered *true*, the body of the `if` *will* get executed.

Finally, the only number that Perl considers to be *false* is zero, so if you pass an empty array

```
my @array = ();
if (@array) { ...
```

it is the same as

```
if (0) { ...
```

and the body of the `if` *won't* get executed.

There is no way of discovering whether a variable exists in Perl. As long as you `use strict`, which you *always* should, Perl won't let you run a program that refers to non-existent variables.

Comment: +1 for "`if` applies a scalar context to its parameter", which is not clear from either https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Compound-Statements or https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Context.

Answer (score 5):

`if(@array)` will be true if `@array` has at least one element.

```
my @array;
if (!@array) { print "empty array\n"; }
push @array, 11;
if (@array) { print "array has at least one element\n"; }
```