# Why does printing a perl array give count?

Tags: arrays, perl

I have the following function which returns an array:

```
sub getUsers() {
    @users[0] = 'test';
    @users[1] = 'test2';
    return @users;
}

@temp = getUsers();
$i = @temp;

print "There are $i users";
```

But when I print it out, it appears as the number `2` (the count of the array). What's happening?

Comment: You assign a scalar value to an array, thus it evaluates in scalar context which in Perl means give me the length of the array.

Comment: @squiguy you got that backwards. :) This is assigning an array to a scalar value.

Comment: @friedo Doh! Dyslexia strikes again...

Comment: related question http://stackoverflow.com/q/19369145/2140859

Comment: What were you expecting it to print?  It looks like you wanted the count of uers.  Also, `@users[0]` should now be `$users[0]` in the assignments.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`$i =` is a scalar assignment, giving the right side of the assignment scalar context; when you mention an array in scalar context, it returns its length.

Answer (score 0):

When you use an array in a scalar context, the array returns the number of items in the array.

From the Perldoc on [Perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#List-value-constructors)

> List assignment in scalar context returns the number of elements produced by the expression on the right side of the assignment...

When you say:

```
$i = @temp;
```

You are taking a list and attempting to assign it to a scalar variable. You are using that array in *scalar context*. Thus, you get the size of the array. (Not the largest index. That's what `$#temp` will get you.

You can use the `scalar` function to force an array in scalar context shen it might not otherwise be:
`
    print "There are " . scalar @foo . " items in the array\n";

The `print` function can take a list of times and not just a single string. It then uses the value of the variable `$,`to join the array.

If you want a list of items, use the [join](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html) to *join* a list into a single string:

```
print "There are " . scalar @foo . " items in the array\n";
print "They are " . join ( ", " $foo ) . ".\n";
```

Comment: `$i = @temp;` is a *scalar* assignment in *void* context. The paragraph your quoted is irrelevant.

Comment: Re "You are taking a list and attempting to assign it to a scalar variable. " Not true. There is no list anywhere in `$i = @temp;`. By your logic, `$i = (5,6,7);` should assign `3` when it actually assigns `7`.